# Is there a way to print info/man pages to PDF?

Tags: command-line, pdf, info

I would like to see **info** or **man** pages in **PDF** format so the **formatting** displays correctly. I see texi file can be converted (with *texi2pdf*) but I don't find any texi files with locate. In this case, I'm interested in the Gpg2 info page.

Comment: did you do updatedb before using locate? locate's database is updated once a day with crond.daily. if you want to use locate files created earlier than 24h from when cron.daily ran, it won't find them.

Comment: No, the info page **info gpg2** @dessert

Comment: Do you need to generate them? The GNU info pages are [all available](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals.html) as PDF files on the GNU website. For example: https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg.pdf

Comment: Yes I totally need to generate them because the gnu pdf files may not be the same version

Comment: Um. Then choose the right version? But in any case, this won't be simple. The info files in `/usr/share/info` are in info format. As you can see if you open one, these were generated *from* the `foo.texinfo` files, but I don't think the `foo.texinfo` are distributed by default. After all, they're already being distributed in a format designed to be displayed correctly. You just need to use `info` to see them.  But try getting the source packages of whatever package's info you want. They might contain the texinfo files.

Comment: @terdon Btw, where are different versions of the info pages stored? I didn't find any other than the one you linked – it says “Version 2.2.0” whereas `gpg2 --version` says “gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11” (in Xenial).

Comment: @dessert I stand corrected. I had assumed they'd all be available, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: Made this little script for both **man** and **info**: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25687487/

Comment: @userDepth … and I took the freedom to correct it using [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net): https://paste.ubuntu.com/25687548/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
i=gpg2; info $i | aha | wkhtmltopdf - $i.pdf
```

creates a decent PDF file.

---

LibreOffice is also able to convert to PDF:

```
i=gpg2; info $i > $i && libreoffice --convert-to pdf $i && rm $i
```

The output can compete with the above solution in my opinion.

---

Also there's `enscript` which offers interesting formatting options (see[`man enscript`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/enscript.1.html)):

```
i=gpg2; info $i > $i; enscript -B -o $i.ps $i; ps2pdf $i.ps $i.pdf && rm $i{,.ps}
```

---

```
info gpg2 | lp -d PDF
```

makes use of CUPS PDF (you might need to install the `cups-pdf` package first) to print a PDF file in `~/PDF/` – but it's not as fancy.

---

```
i=gpg2; info -ao $i.pdf $i
```

also works, but the output is plain ugly.

Comment: FYI this also works for man pages - **man gpg2 | aha | wkhtmltopdf - info_gpg2.pdf**

Answer (score 7):

Others have already answered the question of how to convert `info` pages to PDF, so I'll cover `man` pages (the original and best online documentation!).

On most modern Unix systems you can convert `man` pages to PDF just by using the `-Tpdf` option to `man`, but be aware that it will output to `stdout` so you'll need to redirect it:

```
man -Tpdf man > manpage.pdf
```

If, for any reason, your installed version of `troff`/`groff` (the formatting engine behind man pages) doesn't support direct PDF output then you can use `ps2pdf`, part of Ghostscript:

```
man -Tps man | ps2pdf - manpage.pdf
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the .texi files from the source package:

Use

```
info -w Gpg2
```

to find the .info file. In this case it's `/usr/share/info/gnupg.info.gz`.

Now find the package that contains it:

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/info/gnupg.info.gz
```

This tells you the file is in the package `gnupg`. So download the source package:

```
apt-get source gnupg
```

apt-get tells you

```
Picking 'gnupg2' as source package instead of 'gnupg'
```

and

```
dpkg-source: info: extracting gnupg2 in gnupg2-2.1.15
```

So you should find the .texi files somewhere in the folder `gnupg2-2.1.15/` (in this case they are in `gnupg2-2.1.15/doc`)