# How do I get a readable printed copy of a man page

Tags: printing, libreoffice, manpage

I've a largish man page (psql) that I'm trying to digest.  I've tried redirecting the output of man to a file, but the output confuses LibreOffice enough that whole pages are missing, even if I arrange that the lines wrap properly (I set my window width to 79 before I issue the man command then have LibreOffice change the font size to 10 pt.)

So: I could use a different word processor, I guess.  Or maybe there are better commands to use than man itself.  Or maybe there's a way to bypass LibreOffice and send it directly to my printer (a Brother monochrome laser printer).

In the end, I just need something readable and physical so that I can mark it up with highlighters and write on it.

Comment: Most man pages are [available on the Internet](https://manpages.org/psql) as html. Google the man page you are trying to print. Then print from the browser.

Comment: @user68186 I'm embarrassed I didn't think of that, but when I tried it just now, it only printed a single page.  Not sure how to get it to paginate and still retain the formatting.

Comment: Never mind.  I found a different site without that problem.  You're right- they are all over the place.

Comment: There is also the `man -t` option for outputting in postscript format for a printer.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to print info/man pages to PDF?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962558/is-there-a-way-to-print-info-man-pages-to-pdf)

Comment: I'm baffled that `man | lpr` didn't work.

Comment: @Joshua man | lpr runs, but the output does not qualify as readable.  Lines are wrapped in the middle of words. Tthe font is so large that this happens a lot.  And there's no attempt to style different elemenmts differently.  You'd get about the same result with a monkey and a typewriter, if the monkey was really smart.

Comment: @4dummies: Too bad. I'm used to that working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain a **printed** copy of a man page, say for `psql`, use:

`man -t psql | lpr`

Or as @4dummies suggests, if your printer supports duplexing:

`man -t psql | lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge`

One could even create a `bash` function for convenience:

```
prman() {
  man -t "$1" | lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge
}
```

and then say:

`prman psql`

Comment: Change that to "man -t psql | lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge" and you have a winner.  it's just harder to remember.  I suppose I could write a bash alias for that.

Answer (score 19):

You can output the manpage in html using command options.

example to view the manpage for nano:

```
man --html=firefox nano
```

use:

```
man --help
```

for more information.

<sub>Note that you must have the `groff` package installed. Having the `groff` command alone from the `groff-base` package is not enough.</sub>

Alternatively, you can google "ubuntu manpage packagename" replacing "packagename" with the actual packagename to view the Ubuntu manpages online.

Comment: "use man --help for more information."- or man man.

Comment: Note that one must have the `groff` package installed for this to work, otherwise `man` will exit with an error status and a cryptic error message. Things are confusing because the executable `groff` may already be installed but that alone won't be enough. I've submitted an edit for the answer that adds this information.

Comment: It appears this doesn't work on 18.04 :( I found a solution but not sure if the security implications are worth it and I'd have to look into it further.

Comment: @mchid Interesting, my edit was for 20.04, but I assumed other recent versions wouldn't differ in that respect.

Comment: @undercat Yeah, it's weird. It's always worked on older versions and I used to have an alias set. For now, I'll just use a script with: `man2html $(man -w $1) > $HOME/$1.html; firefox $HOME/$1.html &` instead

Comment: Ummm.  I have groff, but not the whole package.  How do I get that?  Moreover, going through HTML to get to Postscript seems just weird.  But then going to PDF should work, because I know I can print those.

Comment: @4dummies  You can install the full version of `groff` by running `sudo apt install groff`. As mentioned, `groff-base` is installed by default and is a dependency of `groff`. Also, both firefox and google allow you to print using CTRL+P and you can use the "print to file" option to export as a PDF.

Comment: @4dummies If you're getting an error on 18.04, it's because of a security issue and apparmor. The best way to work around that would be to use the script I provided in the other comment or you can run it as a command by replacing `$1` with `psql` like in this example: `man2html $(man -w psql) > $HOME/psql.html; firefox $HOME/psql.html &`

Comment: @4dummies `apt-cache search groff | grep groff`

Comment: @4dummies https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594081/man-html-and-man-gxditview-exit-with-errors

Answer (score 18):

For a PDF:

```
man -t psql > psql.ps
ps2pdf psql.ps
```

Comment: You can avoid the temporary file by doing `man -t psql | ps2pdf - psql.pdf`.

Comment: @flndr Perfect answer to my question

Answer (score 5):

A package called `man2html-base` is already available in the repositories and its job is to convert man pages to an HTML page.

**First**, you need to install it like so:

```
sudo apt install man2html-base
```

**Then**, you need to find the main compressed man page file for the desired package by running a tool like `whereis`... taking `nano` as an example it would be done like so:

```
whereis nano
```

Look in the output for a `.gz` archive file that has got `man` in its path like:

```
/usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz
```

Or use `man -w` *( Thank you to [@mchid's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399761/how-do-i-get-a-readable-printed-copy-of-a-man-page/1399863#comment2428235_1399863) )* to find the file like so:

```
man -w nano
```

**Finally**, once you find that file, you can convert it to HTML like so:

```
man2html /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz > ~/nano.html
```

the `> ~/nano.html` part will redirect the output to a file called `nano.html` in your home directory.

**Notice**:
You can try auto detecting the man page file and converting it in one step utilizing [bash command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) like so:

```
man2html "$(man -w nano)" > ~/nano.html
```

Comment: `man -t` should be the way to go.

Comment: well `man -t nano|ps2txt > nano.txt` anyway.

Comment: @mckenzm That is possible as well as sending the output to `evince` like so `man -t nano | tee - | evince -` then printing or saving it from there ... *evince* comes preinstalled with Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I do not see why you think it is "the way to go"! ... It's just a way of doing it and there are many other ways ... *man2html* is widely used especially to create online copies of man pages plus it creates indexes which you don't get with `man -t`

Comment: @raffa `-t` is available everywhere for historic reasons.  `—html` is not available on non-gnu systems.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Without me delving into an extended discussion of this subject, I would like to express that I value your opinion and your concern ... However this site is askubuntu.com where we help Ubuntu users to get things don on their systems with whatever right means available and then we let them choose what suits them the best... I hope you understand.

Comment: @raffa I thought you would appreciate an approach that did not require a user to "Look in the output for a .gz archive file".  And works everywhere even.  My bad.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I appreciate your presence and your comments :) and I hope that you might add an answer here because you clearly have the knowledge ... but `man -t` is already mentioned in the answer by @flndr ... not that I don't know it but it was already there when I wrote my answer ... plus diversity is good

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `man -w nano` to find the path to the compressed file.

Comment: @Raffa Your command is misguiding a bit because use of `-` as the filename suggests that evince is reading from stdin, which it actually doesn't. Your command creates **an ordinary file** with the name `-` in the current dir with the postscript output (and that is read by evince), which may be an unwanted side effect. I would rather explicitly use a file in `/tmp` and get rid of pipe, which isn't actually used. Something like `man -t nano >/tmp/mantmp && evince /tmp/mantmp`.

Comment: @raj True ... It's a pity that `evince` can't read from STDIN ... If you decide to go with the temporary files way, it can be done easily with `mktemp` like so `et=$(mktemp); man -t nano > "$et"; evince "$et"` ... However, possibilities are endless and things can get more complicated with functions and scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have any KDE applications installed, one clever little trick is to make sure you have the `kio-extras` and `kde-cli-tools` packages installed and run this command

```
kioclient5 copy man:psql file://$HOME/psql.html
```

It's intended to allow you to load `man:psql` in something like KDE's Konqueror web browser/file manager hybrid but `kio_man` will work for anything that supports loading from arbitrary KIOSlaves for its Open File functionality.